# How to fix java.lang.OutOfMemoryError in this case?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-navigation-graph, dynamic-feature-module

I have already searched for OOM issue but I don't know how to fix it.
I am not sure if it is caused by navigation args or view inflater. Please help.
It is highlighted in this line

`io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2ViewCreator.onCreateView (-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:422)`

and this is all of the stack trace
that shows up in Firebase Crashlytics.
Can anyone help me please.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16 byte allocation with 2587088 free bytes and 2526KB until OOM, target footprint 268435456, growth limit 268435456; giving up on allocation because <1% of heap free after GC.
       at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.asSequence(_Collections.kt:3524)
       at kotlin.collections.MapsKt___MapsKt.asSequence(_Maps.kt:591)
       at androidx.navigation.NavDestination.equals(NavDestination.kt:690)
       at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator$DynamicIncludeNavGraph.equals(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:230)
       at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:631)
       at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.replaceWithIncludedNav(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:134)
       at androidx.navigation.dynamicfeatures.DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.onRestoreState(DynamicIncludeGraphNavigator.kt:159)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.kt:1227)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1186)
       at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.kt:1139)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment$navHostController$2.invoke(NavHostFragment.kt:104)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment$navHostController$2.invoke(NavHostFragment.kt:78)
       at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.getNavHostController$navigation_fragment_release(NavHostFragment.kt:78)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.kt:150)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3094)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:504)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:268)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:136)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:247)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:226)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2ViewCreator.onCreateView(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:422)
       at com.lokalise.sdk.LokalisePreInterceptor.inflateView(LokaliseInterceptor.kt:233)
       at com.lokalise.sdk.LokalisePreInterceptor.intercept(LokaliseInterceptor.kt:140)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-InterceptorChain.proceed(-InterceptorChain.kt:30)
       at com.lokalise.sdk.LokalisePostInterceptor.intercept(LokaliseInterceptor.kt:113)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-InterceptorChain.proceed(-InterceptorChain.kt:30)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.ViewPump.inflate(ViewPump.kt:36)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater$PrivateWrapperFactory2.onCreateView(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:399)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:247)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1091)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1019)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:983)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1145)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1148)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1148)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1106)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:57)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:544)
       at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:48)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:56)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:50)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityExtension.kt:79)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.ui.MainActivity$special$$inlined$viewBinding$1.invoke(ActivityExtension.kt:23)
       at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.ui.MainActivity.getBinding(MainActivity.kt:94)
       at com.kingpowerclick.her.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:124)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: I didn't find any logs related to OOM in the stacktrace. Please post relevant logs.

Comment: I update the stacktrace. I forgot to copy the very first line that show OOM @gauravjain

Comment: I checked the stack-trace. It seems that it is trying to compare fragment arguments and to do that, converting it to a sequence. But due to memory issues, it fires up the exception. I think somewhere in your code, memory is being consumed, which is leading to an issue here. It doesn't look possible to solve the leak on basis of the above stack-trace only.